# Gradient coloring in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, color

How can I easily control the color shading of ArrayPlot? Say I want to go from white to dark green in a gradient form.

Comment: how about `ListDensityPlot[matrix, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, White}, #] &),
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]`? (using `matrix` from your other question)

Comment: Yes, worked! Thanksssss

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) and [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) to make a gradient of colors for `ArrayPlot`. Here's an example that uses a gradient of colors from white to dark green.

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = RandomReal[9, {10, 20}];
ArrayPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{a}, Blend[{White, Darker@Green}, a]]]
```

[image: array plot with color function]

`Blend[{color1, color2}, x]` works by mixing a fraction *(1 - x)* of the first color with a fraction *x* of the second color, where *x* is between 0 and 1. A table of 12 colors from white to green shows how `Blend` works.

```
Table[Blend[{White, Darker@Green}, x], {x, Subdivide[0, 1, 11]}]
```

> [image: blended colors]

Answer (score 4):

```
matrix = {{5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

ListDensityPlot[matrix, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, White}, #] &),
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

Use `(Blend[{White, Green}, #] &)` to get

[image]